# Cordova / PhoneGap : open file from other app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, filesystems, uti

I recently started working with PhoneGap based on cordova to build an app for ios, android and windows phones.
For now I'm testing it on iphone, which is the main platform for this app and this question as well.

To make it easier, lets call my PhoneGap application "Scanner".

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

You're in a random app, lets say the mail app. Click on an attachement and select "Open with..." Scanner. That should send the file to the scanner and send the path of that file to a javascript variable.

For now, I had no problem opening the xcode build and adding the document type, so my app is displayed in the open with menu.

Any idea how to get the app to display a file ? A pdf for example ?

If there's a global solution for the 3 platforms, that would be like heaven...

Thanks to all of you !

Answer (score 1):

What you need is called "deep linking"

some plugins.

https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin

Happy codding!

******************* Edit *******************

I see your need, you are talking about Uniform Type Identifiers, but I dont find any information about how to use in cordova. Probably you will need to write your own plugin

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001319

Comment: That's actually not what I need (or I'm missing something).

What I need is to enable my app to open pdf, png, doc, xls and ppt files from mail attachements or other apps (a scanner, your images library...)

Comment: That's way out of my coding skills... thanks anyway :(